# Check RUT (Rol Único Tributario) for numbers over 7 digits

Tags: list-manipulation, modular-arithmetic

In Chile the [RUT (Rol Único Tributario)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Chile) is a national identification number. Every RUT has a check digit modulo 11. The RUT has 7 or 8 digits plus a check digit or letter.

I made this code that works for 7 digit RUTs, but not with 8-digit ones. A 7-digit number has the form abcdef-(check digit) and an 8-digit one is in the form abcdefg-(check digit).

How do I work with 8 digits?

Here are some valid RUT numbers to test the checker function: 9007920-4, 21620312-7, 13621690-2, 9329827-6, 5946647-k, 7425273-7, 17694763-2, 
23212441-5, 21485432-5, 15459172-9, 10218932-9, 11316657-6, 24130358-6, 11377848-2, 18609823-4, 18004377-2, 8784472-2, 12357399-4, 12391279-9, 8304218-4.

```
(* Checker rut*)
rut = Input["Enter your rut without check digit"];
n = IntegerDigits[rut];
d1 = n[[7]];
d2 = n[[6]];
d3 = n[[5]];
d4 = n[[4]];
d5 = n[[3]];
d6 = n[[2]];
d7 = n[[1]];

s = d1*2 + d2*3 + d3*4 + d4*5 + d5*6 + d6*7 + d7*2 (*+d8*3 (8 digits)  *)
ri = Mod[s, 11];
rf = 11 - ri;

If[rf == 11, Print["The check digit is 0"]]
If[rf == 10, Print["The check digit is k"]]
If[rf < 10, Print["The check digit is ", rf]]
```

Comment: Something along these lines: http://www.vesic.org/english/blog/c-sharp/verifying-chilean-rut-code-tax-number/

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I just found that article and I'm writing a mma function now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
check[rut_] := 
 Module[{d = 11 - Mod[Total[IntegerDigits[rut]*{3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}], 11]},
  Which[d == 11, 0, d == 10, "K", True, d]]
```

Takes rut as integer (all digits less check digit), returns check code. Does not validate length of input, so add that if needed.

Update: Since you've added check examples, and since they contain both 7 and 8 body codes, it appears what you want is something that handles both, not just 8 as your title implies. Here's one way:

```
check[rut_Integer] := 
 Module[{d = 11 - Mod[Total[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[rut], 8]*{3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}], 
      11]}, Which[d == "11", 0, d == 10, "k", True, ToString@d]];

check[rut_String] :=
 Module[{chk = StringTake[rut, -1], bod = StringDrop[rut, -2]},
  If[StringLength@rut < 9, check[ToExpression@rut], 
   check[ToExpression[bod]] == chk]]
```

Note I've changed this to return the check code as a string (as your code does). You can call `check` with an integer or string representing the body of the code, and the check code will be returned, or call with the whole code as a string and true/false for validity will be returned.

Using your test examples:

```
tests = {"9007920-4", "21620312-7", "13621690-2", "9329827-6", 
  "5946647-k", "7425273-7", "17694763-2", "23212441-5", "21485432-5", 
  "15459172-9", "10218932-9", "11316657-6", "24130358-6", 
  "11377848-2", "18609823-4", "18004377-2", "8784472-2", "12357399-4",
   "12391279-9", "8304218-4"};

(* Check validity of whole RUT *)
check /@ tests

(* get check code for bodies, as strings, check against tests *)
(check /@ (StringDrop[#, -2] & /@ tests)) == (StringTake[#, -1] & /@tests)

(* get check code for bodies, as integers, check against tests *)
(check /@ (ToExpression@StringDrop[#, -2] & /@ tests)) == (StringTake[#, -1] & /@ tests)

(*
{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, \
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

True

True

*)
```

Comment: @Works thank you explain the code to understand it better, Fdo

Comment: Any reason you use `Total[Times[__]]` instead of `Dot[__]`?  Edge cases I'm not aware of?

Comment: @2012rcampion: No, just thought (based on OP code clip) that making it easy to read inside-out might be easier for OP to grok...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be referring to the [Rol Único Tributario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Chile).

[This article](http://www.vesic.org/english/blog/c-sharp/verifying-chilean-rut-code-tax-number/) gives a verification algorithm. rasher already wrote the algorithm to compute the check digit, so I'll write something slightly different, the verification algorithm.

1. Strip out all non-numeric characters, except an optional trailing `K`.
2. Pad the number to nine digits with zeros on the left.
3. Multiply each of the digits against a list of weights, treating `K` as 10, and total the results.
4. Find the remainder modulo 11.  If it is zero, the number is valid.

Here's the code:

```
verifyRUT[rut_String] := 
 Catch[Mod[
    PadLeft[If[Length[#] > 9, Throw[False], #] &@
       StringCases[
        StringTrim[rut], {d : DigitCharacter :> FromDigits[d], 
         "K" | "k" ~~ Except[DigitCharacter, _] ... ~~ EndOfString -> 
          10}], 9].{3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 11] == 0]
```

<s>Like rasher's function this doesn't test that the input length is not more than nine.</s>  If the length is greater than nine, returns `False`.

This works for all the examples you provided (and returns `False` for the random examples I came up with; still, you may want to include some known malformed RUTs in your test set).

This should also work for RUTs of any length up to nine (including checksum).

Comment: @Waiting upgrade, thanks

Comment: @For some reason your code does not work for me, nothing appears